# When i publish my workflow in SharePoint designer 2013 is only workflow publish or my other form changes also?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I edit my old workflow and make some changes. when I publish, only workflow publish or other my form changes also publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only your workflow publishes. There will be no change on form. The way workflow was referring the list has changed now, rest remain same.

Comment: Thank you for reply i have one questions, When i publish workflow it reflect on my all user or only my localhost site?

Comment: on all users...everyone.... you have published it. Its applicable everywhere now who ever is accessing the site. mark it as answer if you are satisfied with answer